interaction.editReply not working with my messageComponentCollector - Discord.js
Basically I'm building a bot using discord js. A command of the bot allowing my user to filter the object on sales on my website generates a message with maximum 10 embeds, each one representing an image of an object. 10 embeds per message being the limit set by discord. Given the fact that there might be more than 10 objects respecting the filters, I created buttons to allow the user to see the next or previous 10 objects. When clicking on the buttons, rather than sending a new message with the 10 new objects to display I would like to update the initial message.
Nevertheless i'm a bit stuck right now to find a solution, the code extract of code below gives me the following error: Error [InteractionNotReplied]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.
const reply = await interaction.reply({
        embeds: embedsToDisplay,
        components: [buttonRow],
        ephemeral: true,
      });

      const collector = reply.createMessageComponentCollector({
        componentType: ComponentType.Button,
      });

      collector.on("collect", async (interaction) => {
        if (interaction.customId === "seeNext10Items") {
          counterOfItemTenLowerRange++;
          counterOfItemTenUpperRange++;
          seePrevious10Items.setDisabled(false);
          embedsToDisplay = result
            .slice(
              counterOfItemTenLowerRange * 10,
              counterOfItemTenUpperRange * 10
            )
            .map((item) => embedCreator.createEmbedResponseFilterHdv(item));

          if (counterOfItemTenUpperRange === numberOfItemDividedByTen) {
            seeNext10Items.setDisabled(true);
          }

          await interaction.editReply({
            embeds: embedsToDisplay,
            components: [buttonRow],
            ephemeral: true,
          });
          return;
        }
        if (interaction.customId === "seePrevious10Items") {
          counterOfItemTenLowerRange--;
          counterOfItemTenUpperRange--;
          seeNext10Items.setDisabled(false);
          embedsToDisplay = result
            .slice(
              counterOfItemTenLowerRange * 10,
              counterOfItemTenUpperRange * 10
            )
            .map((item) => embedCreator.createEmbedResponseFilterHdv(item));

          if (counterOfItemTenLowerRange === 0) {
            seePrevious10Items.setDisabled(true);
          }

          interaction.editReply({
            embeds: embedsToDisplay,
            components: [buttonRow],
            ephemeral: true,
          });
          return;
        }
      });

I tried to use other discord interaction function like followUp or update, but I'm still facing the same issue. I think the error comes from this part of the code
const reply = await interaction.reply({
        embeds: embedsToDisplay,
        components: [buttonRow],
        ephemeral: true,
      });


I can see two issues in your code here:

Based on the start of your code, you have access to the interaction variable. This suggests that you are replying to a component interaction at the start. You then go on to create a new component collector on this reply message and use the same keyword (interaction) as an argument in that collector. This is poor coding practice and could potentially lead to further issues down the line. I suggest using a different keyword argument. This point will be relevant in my suggested solution later.
While I think I understand what you have tried to do, there is a problem with the code structure. The first line of your code sends a reply to the first interaction, and stores a Message object inside the reply variable. So your reply variable now simply represents a Message object. When you create a new component collector on this message, called collector, you need to first acknowledge (defer or reply to) the first interaction on this component collector. Your code simply uses editReply() despite a reply to a collector interaction not existing. This is why you are getting your error.

There are two approaches you can take here. You can either choose to:

Simply edit() the reply message that has the new collector, or
You can use editReply() on the initial interaction itself (the one you have replied to and stored the message into reply).

In the first solution, you will need to firstly use a different keyword to interaction inside collector since interaction is already in use by this point. I will use collectorInteraction from here on for this to avoid confusion. You should then be able to simply use await reply.edit() instead of await collectorInteraction.editReply() for each place you have used editReply().
In the second solution, you don't need collector. You can perform your conditional checks and actions after the initial interaction reply, and then use editReply(). I suggest this solution as this is the intended purpose of the editReply() function. I have provided some code below:


if (!(interaction.replied)) {
  const reply = await interaction.reply({
    embeds: embedsToDisplay,
    components: [buttonRow],
    ephemeral: true,
  });
}

if (interaction.customId === "seeNext10Items") {
  counterOfItemTenLowerRange++;
  counterOfItemTenUpperRange++;
  seePrevious10Items.setDisabled(false);
  embedsToDisplay = result
    .slice(
      counterOfItemTenLowerRange * 10,
      counterOfItemTenUpperRange * 10
    )
    .map((item) => embedCreator.createEmbedResponseFilterHdv(item));

  if (counterOfItemTenUpperRange === numberOfItemDividedByTen) {
    seeNext10Items.setDisabled(true);
  }

  await interaction.editReply({
    embeds: embedsToDisplay,
    components: [buttonRow],
    ephemeral: true,
  });
  return;
}
if (interaction.customId === "seePrevious10Items") {
  counterOfItemTenLowerRange--;
  counterOfItemTenUpperRange--;
  seeNext10Items.setDisabled(false);
  embedsToDisplay = result
    .slice(
      counterOfItemTenLowerRange * 10,
      counterOfItemTenUpperRange * 10
    )
    .map((item) => embedCreator.createEmbedResponseFilterHdv(item));

  if (counterOfItemTenLowerRange === 0) {
    seePrevious10Items.setDisabled(true);
  }

  interaction.editReply({
    embeds: embedsToDisplay,
    components: [buttonRow],
    ephemeral: true,
  });
  return;
}



